# How to copy tables from sql server to ms access using python and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I want to copy tables from MS SQL server to MS access using sqlalchemy. 
But I don't know how to do it. Please help. Here is the code.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import select, Table, MetaData
import sqlalchemy_access
import urllib



# =============================================================================
# # Create tables from mssql
# =============================================================================
connection_string_ms = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};'
    r'Server=myserver;'
    r'Database=mydb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
connection_url_ms = f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string_ms)}'

engine_ms = create_engine(connection_url_ms)


# Create a MetaData instance
metadata_ms = MetaData(bind = engine_ms)

address = Table('ADDRESS', metadata_ms, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine_ms)


# =============================================================================
# # Paste table into access database
# =============================================================================
connection_string_access = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=myaccessdb.accdb;'
    r'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;'
)
connection_url = f'access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string_access)}'

engine = create_engine(connection_url)

address.create(engine)
```

Then error pops up

ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition. (-3553) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Thank you.

Comment: you'll have to structure this to hold the data during the transfer for example, you'll need something like pandas (pd.read_sql will accept sqlachemy engines & statements) then write. there isn't a way to write directly wo a connection from access.

Comment: @brddawg Thank you for your reply. I ended up using dataframe first and then write into access.